# Netbeans c/c++ remote execution

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, remote-server

I have a couple of problems.

1. I have setup remote building in netbeans for a C/C++ project, but now I want to run the project remotely. I must run this on an hpc(high performance computing) system that uses a batch system for job scheduling. The batch system requires you to setup the environment(eg number of cores, load modules). So how do I make netbeans execute a shell script that sets all this up and then runs the executable instead of just the executable directly when I run remotely?
2. I added a .bash script to the c/c++ project, but whenever that file gets copied to the remote server on a build event, the file ends up with garbage...a bunch of ^@^@^@^@^@^@^ repeated...this seems to occur whenever I add a new non-source file...I know my line endings are unix.

Comment: Is it about C++ as per the title or about C as per the tag?

Comment: Either. It makes no difference in the context.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your first question:

I had a similar problem and solved it by creating a shell script that takes just a couple of input parameters but otherwise handles everything required to run my project on the remote server. Then in Netbeans, I right clicked on my project, selected Properties, selected Run, and set the Run Command to call the shell script as follows:

```
/bin/sh pcrun2.sh param1 param2
```

where /bin/sh is the command to run a shell script, pcrun2.sh is the shell script that will set up the environment as needed and then run my project, and param1 and param2 are the input parameters the shell script needs in order to run.

I can't answer to your second question. My project resides entirely on the remote server. I created my shell script (pcrun2.sh) locally on a windows machine (but with Linux line endings) and then copied it to the directory on the remote host where my project is and that I have read/write access to.